# Getting Erorr ECONNRESET intermittently with mosquitto and node.js

Tags: node.js, centos, mosquitto, mqtt.js

I am getting an intermittent error at node.js end intermittently while subscribing the topic from MQTT.
I have configured MQTT log files and found the below error
`Unable to accept new connection, system socket count has been exceeded. Try increasing "ulimit -n" or equivalent.`

While I am encounter the above message at mqtt logile, I am getting the error ECONNRESET at node.js end at the same time.

I have checked the ulimit at the server end and gives me the below details

```
 ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256380
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

My Linux version is as below

```
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1062.12.1.vz7.131.10
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Is the problem is related to uilmit? Do I need to increase the value of ulimit at server level?
How to fix the issue for ECONRESET at node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the `open files` count on the broker.

You can do it for the running process with the `prlimit` command, but you should do it for the user running mosquitto so it's persistent across restarts. You can do this by editing the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file. You will need to log out and back in for it to take effect for a normal user and probably restart the service for a daemon user.

Comment: Do I need to change the `open files` parameter at the server where broker is running? Could you please share any link as how to change the `open files` count at mosquitto.conf?

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435770/828193, systemd doesn't follow the global limit, you must edit service's conf file.